# Migrating a JCA deployment in Wildfly to Quarkus: Easy guide for legacy resource adapter migration

Tags: quarkus

Is there any guide to migrate a JCA deployed in Wildfly to Quarkus ?

I was looking for an easy way to possibly deploy a legacy resource adapter in Quarkus without major refactoring. is there any recommendation ? Is JCA actually supported by Quarkus ?

Comment: Quarkus does not support JCA, no.

Comment: @Ladicek that sounds like a proper answer to me (as opposed to a comment) :)